# webgl bufferSubData call cost vs cost of transfering bytes

Tags: performance, graphics, buffer, webgl

I have an array buffer. Parts of the buffer needs to be changed, and parts do not need to be changed. If the parts of the buffer that needs change are subsequent, a call to bufferSubData ranging over the part that needs to be changed is more efficient than updating the whole buffer, including changing bytes that does not need to change. The problem is if the bytes that need changing are far apart within the buffer, with many bytes between that does not need changing. Is it better to make two bufferSubData calls for each chunk that needs updating, or is it better to just make one call that unnecessarily update the ones in between as well? How costly is a bufferSubData call versus updating one more byte of data?

Comment: There's no easy answer. Every driver and every browser will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `bufferSubData` is routed to native `glBufferSubData` provided by the driver, it is best to be avoided altogether. It is known to be extremely slow in some mobile GPU drivers. See [this page](https://dolphin-emu.org/blog/2013/09/26/dolphin-emulator-and-opengl-drivers-hall-fameshame/) for reference  (search for `glBufferSubData`).
I have run into extreme `glBufferSubData` slowness in quite recent mobile GPUs used on Android devices (Mali, PowerVR, Adreno). Interestingly, not on PowerVR GPUs used with iOS, which clearly indicates a software issue. The practical approach which seems to run well everywhere is replacing the whole buffer with `glBufferData` once per frame (or as few times as possible, combining the data for multiple draw calls).